# CSS increase width only if max-height reached

Tags: jquery, css, height

I want to make a div with max-height and initial width and increase the width only if the content reaches the max-height value? Is it possible to do that without JavaScript?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/zn77t0r1/

UPDATE:

If not, how to do it easily with JS or jQuery?

Comment: How is the content increasing in size? If your content is fixed, but your div is shrinking, you could use media queries to check the height of your page.

Comment: It is div with some class, but it can contain text of variable length.

Comment: Can you post you markup and styles, or create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowing jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(resizeWidth()); //call function when page is loaded
$(window).resize(resizeWidth()); //call function when page is resized

function resizeWidth(){
    var maxHeight = $('.container').eq(0).css('max-height');
    maxHeight = maxHeight.split('px')[0];//remove px
    var cWidth = $('.container').eq(0).width();
    var currHeight = $('div.container')[0].scrollHeight;

    while(maxHeight < currHeight)
    {
        cWidth += 100;
        $('.container').eq(0).css('width', cWidth + 'px' );
        currHeight = $('div.container')[0].scrollHeight;
    }

}
```

The function keeps adding 100px to the width as long as the text is higher than the div's `max-height`.

[jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zn77t0r1/5/)

Answer (score 4):

So you have to know what the height of your div is to increase the width of it.

Something like

```
If (height >= max-height)  //change width
```

This is not possible with only css or html.
But it is very easy to do with jQuery, if you don't mind using it.

This should do it:

```
//call function when page is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeWidth();
}); 

//call function when page is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
    resizeWidth();
}); 

function resizeWidth(){

    var maxHeight = 250; // your max-height in px
    if ($('.container').height() >= maxHeight) {
        $('.container').css('max-width', '400px');
    }else {
        $('.container').css('max-width', '200px');
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, let's allow jQuery, then.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/zn77t0r1/1/ but it's not working and I think that the code does not cope with the text inside, it is designed only to skip between two sizes.

Comment: i changed the code a little. Im not sure if its what you want but im sure you can play with it and get it right. cheers